# Required attribute 'pageBaseType' not found - YSOD when launching my MVC 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

since this morning I keep getting this error when trying to launch my MVC 3 application:

```
Required attribute 'pageBaseType' not found.
```

[image: Error Message]

Google did not reveal much useful information and I am not aware of any changes made to web.config other than adding MVCMailer.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: +1 for source control.  Ext.Net bit me with this when I removed it via Nuget.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I received this same error, also after installing MvcMailer. The error was coming not from the root Web.config, but from a web.config under the view folder. I compared this to a new MVC 3 project and found my version, updated by some package, had changed the  setting to:

```
<pages>
```

from the default:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

Changing this back to the default removed the error.

EDIT:

and adding back in...

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

and..

```
<system.web>
<pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
```

Comment: I found that I was also missing `<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

Comment: thanks , mvcmailer is too bad ... recommentd actionmailer.mvc

Comment: MvcMailer totally screwed me up too...still trying to get things back in working order

Comment: For myself, I couldn't copy and paste the code above.  I had to create a new project and copy and paste from that.  I will also be trying actionmailer.  Thanks for the tip, dfang.

Comment: Uninstall of MvcSiteMapProvider messed up the Views\Web.config for us too. Rolling back to a previous version from source control helped us fix it. The differences where the same as above.